# How can I get a server's IP address in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux

I want to setup a Linux server. How can I get the IP address for the Linux machine, so that I can use this IP to load the page on another machine?

Comment: Localhost ip for the machine? ifconfig will show you that (from command line)

Answer (score 3):

`ifconfig` will show you the IP address configured on the interface. So does the modern equivalent `ip addr` (yes, that's two words; the command is `ip` and the parameter is `addr`). Try:

```
ip addr | grep 'inet '
```

which will show all IPv4 addresses assigned to interfaces currently up on your machine.

If you need the external IP address, there are numerous services which can tell you about that. [Here's one.](http://checkip.dns.he.net/)

Answer (score 0):

As Daruis has commented, calling

> ifconfig

from the Shell (using a Terminal Emulator) would display various related network data, such as your IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command

```
ip a
```

It will display more information related to network interfaces such as lo, ethernet interface, wireless network interface etc.